# Sabre Credit Card Verification Error

Tags: credit-card, sabre

Sabre Credit card verification SOAP API always shows invalid Currency

`<CreditVerificationRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.1.0">
   <Credit>
      <CC_Info>
         <PaymentCard AirlineCode="BG" Code="CA" ExpireDate="2018-03" Number="CardNumber" />
      </CC_Info>
      <ItinTotalFare>
         <TotalFare Amount="350" CurrencyCode="USD" />
      </ItinTotalFare>
   </Credit>
</CreditVerificationRQ>`

Comment: Can you provide more information?
Your IPCC for example...?

Comment: Can you add the response? to see the exact error you're getting?